# Building UI of JavaFX app based on web technologies stack

Tags: html, user-interface, webview, javafx

I'm going to build **JavaFX** complex app, with many screens & animations.  in the beginning I plan to use FXML based UI, but now I'm considering using HTML5+CSS+JS, making use of Web View. Could this be done? Have you ever seen desktop app build on such an architecture?

Comment: Did you manage to do it with dukescript? I'm facing the same decision

Comment: @JoãoPereira, sorry, can't help. In the end, I've given up on building that app with dukescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at DukeScript (http://dukescript.com) it does use java for the logic and html for the UI

Answer (score 1):

DukeScript looks interesting. Another solution is WebFX, you can mix and match html and fxml, still running in a webview. See [here](https://github.com/brunoborges/webfx) and [here](https://github.com/pjBooms/webfx).